# paso de parámetros en FromBody a un controlador de ASP.NET Core desde Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

Necesito desde mi aplicacion en Angular necesito recuperar las ofertas en funcion de los años seleccionados con lo cual tengo que pasara a la accion de mi controlador dichos años pero como en Angular leo que no se pueden pasar en el FromBody desde un Get hago esto

```
 getOfertasByYears(years: number[]) {
const config = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json') };

return this.http.post<Oferta[]>(`${this.urlWebAPI}/ofertas/years`, years, config)
  .pipe(
    tap(data => console.log(`Ofertas de los años ${years}: ${data.length}`)
    ),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
```

}

y en el controlador tengo esto

```
[HttpPost("years")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Oferta>>> GetOfertasByYears([FromBody] List<int> years)
    {
      return await _context.Ofertas.Where(o => years.Contains(o.FechaPresentacionFulcrum.Year)).OrderBy(o => o.FechaPresentacionFulcrum).ToListAsync();

    }
```

Pero cuando ejecuto la llamada desde Angular el código nunca llega al Controlador donde he puesto un punto de parada.

Sin embargo cuando hago la llamada desde postman si que llega

[image: postman]

Alguna idea por favor?

Salu2

Comment: Creo que es el tipo de `number[]` con `List<int>` que no lo coge bien. Haz una cosa pásale un string que sea el JSON entero y en la función espera dicho string haber si te llega. Si te llega es el tipo de lista que no le esta gustando.

Comment: @JordiTurell ese no es el problema por que ahora si me funciona sin tocar la fila de los métodos ni las llamadas. El problema creo que estaba en que el resultado de la llamada lo metía en una constante y hasta que no me suscriba a ella no veía el resultado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no estaba en las llamadas sino al obtener el resultado.

Una vez me he suscrito al mismo ya veo valores

Si me quedo aqui

```
private getOfertasXAños(años) {
console.log(`Años seleccionados ${años}`);
let years: number[] = [];
for (let año of años) {
  console.log('Año', año)
  years.push(+año)
}

const ofertas$ = this.dataService.getOfertasByYears(years);
const concursos$ = this.dataServiceConcursos.getConcursosByYears(years);
const organismos$ = this.dataService.getOrganismosAños(years);
const responsables$ = this.dataService.getResponsables();
const invitaciones$ = this.dataServiceInvitaciones.getInvitacionesAños(years);
const licitacionesEnSolitario$ = this.dataService.getLicitacionesEnSolitarioAños(years);
const licitacionesEnUte$ = this.dataService.getLicitacionesEnUTEAños(years);
```

No veo nada pero asi si

```
private getOfertasXAños(años) {
console.log(`Años seleccionados ${años}`);
let years: number[] = [];
for (let año of años) {
  console.log('Año', año)
  years.push(+año)
}

const ofertas$ = this.dataService.getOfertasByYears(years);
const concursos$ = this.dataServiceConcursos.getConcursosByYears(years);
const organismos$ = this.dataService.getOrganismosAños(years);
const responsables$ = this.dataService.getResponsables();
const invitaciones$ = this.dataServiceInvitaciones.getInvitacionesAños(years);
const licitacionesEnSolitario$ = this.dataService.getLicitacionesEnSolitarioAños(years);
const licitacionesEnUte$ = this.dataService.getLicitacionesEnUTEAños(years);

this.dataService.getLicitadoresAños(años)
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.licitadores = data;
    }
    , err => console.error(err)
    , () => {
      const ofertasConPropiedadesMapadas$ = forkJoin([
        ofertas$,
        concursos$,
        organismos$,
        responsables$,
        invitaciones$,
        licitacionesEnSolitario$,
        licitacionesEnUte$
      ])
        .pipe(
          map(([ofertas, concursos, organismos, responsables, invitaciones, licitacionesEnSolitario, licitacionesEnUte]) =>
            ofertas.map(oferta => ({
              ...oferta,
              añoPresentada: new Date(oferta.fechaPresentacionFulcrum).getFullYear(),
              organismoId: (concursos as Concurso[]).find(c => c.id == oferta.concursoId)?.organismoId,
              organismoNombre: oferta.origen == "Concurso"
                ? (organismos as Organismo[]).find(o => o.id == (concursos as Concurso[]).find(c => c.ofertaId == oferta.id)?.organismoId)?.nombre
                : (organismos as Organismo[]).find(o => o.id == (invitaciones as Invitacion[]).find(i => i.ofertaId == oferta.id)?.organismoId)?.nombre,
              presupuesto: oferta.origen == "Concurso"
                ? (concursos as Concurso[]).find(c => c.ofertaId == oferta.id)?.importe
                : (invitaciones as Invitacion[]).find(i => i.ofertaId == oferta.id)?.importe,
              responsableOfertaNombre: (responsables as Responsable[]).find(r => r.id == oferta.responsableOferta)?.nombreCompleto,
              responsableTecnicoNombre: (responsables as Responsable[]).find(r => r.id == oferta.responsableTecnico)?.nombreCompleto,
              concurso: (concursos as Concurso[]).find(c => c.ofertaId == oferta.id),
              invitacion: (invitaciones as Invitacion[]).find(i => i.ofertaId == oferta.id),
              adjudicatarioEnSolitario: (licitacionesEnSolitario as LicitacionEnSolitario[]).find(ls => ls.ofertaId == oferta.id && ls.adjudicado == true)?.licitadorId,
              licitacionesEnUte: (licitacionesEnUte as LicitacionEnUte[]).filter(l => l.ofertaId == oferta.id),
              adjudicada: this.getAdjudicada(oferta.id),
            }) as Oferta))
        );

      ofertasConPropiedadesMapadas$
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.dataSource = data;
          }
          , err => console.error(err)
          , () => {
            console.log(`Ofertas de los años ${años}: con propiedades mapeada ${this.dataSource.length}`);
            //console.log(`dataSource con las 100 primeras ${this.dataSource}`);
          }
        );
    }
  );
```

}

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Saludos :D